# Displaying percentages next to legend items in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, legend, arcgis-10.4

I'm using ArcMap 10.4.1 and I have a map showing points on a map.

Each point represents a measurement of a specific radio frequency and has an attribute of signal strength.

The legend displays discrete bins of data within a range of possible radio frequency values.  I want to display the percentage of total points in each bin.

When I use the Legend Properties I'm able to display the count of points in each bin (checked 'show feature count' box in image below), but not the percentage.

[image: Legend Properties]
This displays the count (in parenthesis) in each bin like in the map below:

[image]

How can I add percentage instead of count to my legend?

Comment: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/98364

Answer (score 1):

For something dynamic I think you will need to find/submit an [ArcGIS Idea](https://geonet.esri.com/community/arcgis-ideas/).

At the moment there are a [number of ArcGIS Ideas that are in the same vicinity](https://geonet.esri.com/search.jspa?q=legend%20percentage&place=%2Fplaces%2F478947&depth=ALL) but they all seem to be more focussed on what appears on the Symbology tab of the Layer Properties rather than what appears in a Legend Element of a Layout (even though the two would be quite related).

You could do something manual using ArcPy to draw graphics and text to look like a legend element but that would be non-trivial and will need to be a new question accompanied by code to illustrate what you have tried.

Comment: Rather than creating text elements, you could try modifying the labels using [UniqueValuesSymbology](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/uniquevaluessymbology-class.htm).  Also non-trivial as you'll have to count the values for each class and manually calculate the percentage.  It also won't be dynamic.

Comment: Good idea @Fezter